# How do vectors that form a basis of Nullspace describe the position of pivot columns in the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across a problem from the MIT Linear Algebra exam and I can't understand the solution. In the problem, vectors that form a basis for the column space and nullspace of some real Matrix A are given, and it asks to give an example of matrix A. In the solution, the position of independent columns is defined by vectors of Nullspace as far as I understand, and I cant figure out why.

[image: description of the problem]

[image: solution]

Answer (score 2):

A key fact about the nullspace is that a vector from the nullspace of $A$ describes a relation between the columns of $A$.

As an example, let's consider what the solution said regarding the first nullspace element. Let $\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\dots,\mathbf v_5$ denote the columns of $A$. The fact that the vector $\mathbf x = (1,-1,0,0,0)$ is in the nullspace of $A$ allows us to make the following deduction:
\begin{align}
&A\mathbf x = 0 \\
\implies & x_1\mathbf v_1 + x_2 \mathbf v_2 + x_3 \mathbf v_3 + x_4 \mathbf v_4 + x_5 \mathbf v_5 = \mathbf 0\\
\implies & (1)\mathbf v_1 + (-1)\mathbf v_2 + (0) \mathbf v_3 + (0) \mathbf v_4 + (0) \mathbf v_5 = \mathbf 0 \\
\implies & \mathbf v_1 - \mathbf v_2 = \mathbf 0 \implies \mathbf v_1 = \mathbf v_2
\end{align}
In other words, the fact that $\mathbf x$ is an element of the nullspace of $A$ tells us that $\mathbf v_1 = \mathbf v_2$.